# WPF - ListBoxItem - Change DataTemplate element colors dynamically

Tags: wpf, data-binding, dynamic, custom-controls, listboxitem

There are several articles written about similar tasks to this.  However, none seem to be close enough to work for what I am doing.  I have a custom control that has a ListBox in its template.  I have reworked the template for the ListBox to my liking.  When an item is selected, I want to change the color.  Here's the part where my problem seems to diverge to most others:  I don't know what color.  It is whatever color is in the item being rendered.  I bound the different colors in XAML, but it doesn't redraw when I set a new color.  I have changed the default color in the items to make sure that the template was picking up the right values in the first place.  That succeeded.  Things I have tried:  binding, having the items implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and EventTrigger with Storyboard (which never really built I assume because my value wasn't a static resource).  I am missing something very basic here.  I'm sure.  Here are code excerpts to help:

XAML:

```
<Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="{Binding CurrentState.Border}" BorderThickness="1">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayObject}" Foreground="{Binding CurrentState.Foreground}" Background="{Binding CurrentState.Background}" MinHeight="12" MinWidth="50" Padding="2" ToolTip="{Binding ToolTip}"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Helper classes:

```
public class MultiStateSelectionGridState
{
    public string Background { get; set; }
    public string Foreground { get; set; }
    public string Border { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public MultiStateSelectionGridState()
    {
        Background = "White";
        Foreground = "Black";
        Border = "Black";
        Text = String.Empty;
    }
};

public interface IMultiStateSelectionGridItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    object DisplayObject { get; }
    object ToolTip { get; }
    object Value { get; }
    MultiStateSelectionGridState CurrentState { get; set; }
    void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e);
};
```

I don't know how much of the item class I can post, so I will not do so initially.  It looks like the following though:

```
class SomeItem : IMultiStateSelectionGridItem
{
    public int SomeInt { get; set; }
    public string SomeString { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherString { get; set; }

    public object DisplayObject
    {
        get { return SomeString + CurrentState.Text; }
    }

    public object ToolTip
    {
        get { return SomeOtherString; }
    }

    public object Value
    {
        get { return SomeInt; }
    }

    private MultiStateSelectionGridState m_currentState;

    public MultiStateSelectionGridState CurrentState 
    {
        get
        {
            return m_currentState;
        }

        set
        {
            m_currentState = value;
            //Notice that this was just test code and I tried CurrentState, Background, and what 
            //you see there now.
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CurrentState.Background"));
        }
    }

    public SomeItem()
    {
        SomeInt = 0;
        SomeString = String.Empty;
        SomeOtherString = String.Empty;
        CurrentState = new MultiStateSelectionGridState();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
    }
};
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Firstly I'm not a fan of referring Colors in code-behind and rather opt to keep them in the xaml to my best extents. Is that even fine for you? Also am I correct in guessing you only want this dynamic Color applying when the item is selected?

Comment: If I knew what colors, that would be fine.  I'm trying to make this very flexible.  And the short answer is that I do what it applying upon selection.  I'm changing what selected means after I get over this hump, but I do want the color to change upon selection.  It is probably worth noting that although I am changing the color to a specific one in the example that it is just a placeholder, @Viv .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok your implementing INPC in `SomeItem` and not `MultiStateSelectionGridState` so when you switch state you need to pretty much create a new `CurrentState` object than go something like `CurrentState.Background = "Blue";` in code-behind

You also need to switch

```
OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CurrentState.Background"));
```

to

```
OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CurrentState"));
```

Now when you switch the `CurrentState` variable(when item is selected) it will propagate to the View and it's properties will be queried accordingly.

I tested this by doing something like:

```
Items = new ObservableCollection<SomeItem> {
  new SomeItem {
    CurrentState = new MultiStateSelectionGridState()
  }
};

// Simulating a Selected State change
var tempTask = new Task
  (
  () => {
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    Items[0].CurrentState = new MultiStateSelectionGridState {
      Background = "Green",
      Border = "Blue"
    };
  },
  TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning
  );
tempTask.Start();
```

and having `ListBox` have it's `ItemsSource` as `Items` from above.

You can find a working example of this [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fu4ir9gn7n8d9hv/MvvmLight2.rar)

If you do not want to keep re-creating the `CurrentState` object for state changes, make 
`MultiStateSelectionGridState` implement INPC itself.

**Side-note**

I do not know where or when you actually get to know what Colors to set for the control, so cant advise how to move that to xaml. But you should look to having these come from xaml

Comment: I could just about yell right now.  I knew it would be something simple.  It works now.  Thanks for the help!